# Lower Bound on the Tail of a Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds, distribution-tails

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}\left(n, \frac{1-\varepsilon}{2}\right)$, for $\varepsilon\in(0, 1)$. I believe that the following anti-concentration bound holds:

$$\Pr\left(X \geq \frac{n}{2}\right) \geq \frac{1}{2}\left[1-\sqrt{1-\exp\left(-\frac{n\varepsilon^2}{1-\varepsilon^2}\right)}\,\right].$$

For the case where $n$ is even, the bound can be shown by:

1. Applying [Slud's Inequality](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-5/issue-3/Distribution-Inequalities-for-the-Binomial-Law/10.1214/aop/1176995801.full): If $k$ is an integer with $p < 1/2$ and $np \leq k \leq n(1-p)$, then $\Pr(X\geq k) \geq \Pr\left(Z \geq \frac{k−n}{\sqrt{np(1−p)}}\right)$, where $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p)$ and $Z \sim \operatorname{N}(0, 1)$.
2. Applying the standard normal tail bound $\Pr(Z \geq t) \geq \frac{1}{2}(1 - \sqrt{1 - \exp(-t^2)})$

Unfortunately, Slud's inequality does not hold for non-integer $k$ (e.g. pick $n = 1$ and $p = k < 1/2$), so this chain of reasoning only works for even $n$ (so that $n/2$ is an integer).

It thus remains to show the bound for when $n$ is odd, but I was unable to make much progress in this case.